# MongoDB get object id by finding on another column value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to querying dbs and especially mongodb.If I run :

```
db.<customers>.find({"contact_name: Anny Hatte"})
```

I get:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("55f7076079cebe83d0b3cffd"), 
  "company_name" : "Gap", 
  "contact_name" : "Anny Hatte", 
  "email" : "ahatte@gmail.com" 
}
```

I wish to get the value of the "_id" attribute from this query result. How do I achieve that?

Similarly, if I have another collection, named items, with the following data:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("55f7076079cebe83d0b3d009"), 
  "_customer" : ObjectId("55f7076079cebe83d0b3cfda"), 
  "school" : "St. Patrick's" 
}
```

Here, the `"_customer"` field is the `"_id"` of the customer collection (the previous collection). I wish to get the `"_id"`, the `"_customer"` and the `"school"` field values for the record where `"_customer"` of items-collection equals `"_id"` of customers-collection.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I wish to get the value of the "_id" attribute from this query result.
>   How do I achieve that?*

The [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find) method returns a cursor to the results, which you can iterate and retrieve the documents in the result set. You can do this using [`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#with-foreach-method).

```
var cursor = db.customers.find({"contact_name: Anny Hatte"});
cursor.forEach(function(customer){
//access all the attributes of the document here
var id = customer._id;
})
```

You could make use of the aggregation pipeline's [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-aggregation) stage that has been introduced as part of `3.2`, to look up and fetch the matching rows in some other related collection.

```
db.customers.aggregate([
{$match:{"contact_name":"Anny Hatte"}},
{$lookup:{
  "from":"items",
  "localField":"_id",
  "foreignField":"_customer",
  "as":"items"
}}
])
```

In case you are using a previous version of mongodb where the stage is not supported, then, you would need to fire an extra query to lookup the items collection, for each customer.

```
db.customers.find(
  {"contact_name":"Anny Hatte"}).map(function(customer){
  customer["items"] = [];
  db.items.find({"_customer":customer._id}).forEach(function(item){
     customer.items.push(item);
  })
  return customer;
})
```